# NodeJS `isolated-vm`: How to reference a function inside the isolate

Tags: node.js, npm, reference, v8, isolate

The following code:

```js
const ivm = require('isolated-vm');

const isolate = new ivm.Isolate();
const context = isolate.createContextSync();

context.setSync('log', new ivm.Callback(x => console.log(x)));
// receives a function and triggers it on an interval
context.setSync('onEvent', new ivm.Callback((handler) => {
   setInterval(() => handler(), 1000)
}));

const script = isolate.compileScriptSync(`onEvent(() => log('hello'))`);
script.runSync(context);
```

Produces the following error:

```
function '() => log('hello')' could not be cloned
```

I understand why a function cannot be copied from one isolate to another, But I would like to get back a reference to that callback so I can trigger it later with `ref.apply(..)`.

How can I get a reference to a function from inside the isolate?

*(without exposing the `ivm` module itself to the isolate which is unsafe)*

Comment: were you able to figure this out? If yes, could you answer your q with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
context.evalClosureSync(`
  globalThis.console = {
    log: $0
  }
`,
[
   (...args) => console.log(...args)
]);
```

Is this code solving your issue?

Comment: Nope, how do you pass callbacks from inside the isloate to the outside